# Count the number of occurrences of a specific string/word in the filenames of files in a folder?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have a folder (using Windows) with files of all types/extensions. I want to search just the filenames and see how many times a certain string/word appears in these filenames. It seems that Linux has grep which could be useful, but the "equivalent" findstr and find commands don't seem to fill my needs.

Comment: @KJ `find "File(s)"` is a bad idea because `dir` output varies depending on language. It's much better to use powershell for these

Comment: Something like this: `wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and path='\\windows\\system32\\' and filename like '%string%'" get filename|find /v /c ""` (Output value is inreased by 1. `string` is the search word in example.)

Comment: Alan, please try to explain what you're trying to do, this time by prvoviding us with an example directory, example flenames, your required result and your actual result. There is an [edit] button directly under your question, you can use to update it with that information. Generally find.exe and findstr.exe will only tell you if a string contains a certain string/word, not how many times it contains it, so if you wanted to use those, you'd effectively need to break the string into each different permutation of substrings for that search terms' length, and check each of those.

Comment: Would a file `txt-txt.txt` count as `1`, `2` or `3`? What about `txtxt.txt`?